# Expose JpaSpecificationExecutor method as REST resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Say I have this interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
}
```

Is it possible to expose a method from a `JpaSpecificationExecutor` within interface annotated with `@RepositoryRestResource` as REST resource?

If so, how I get my custom `Specification` implementation from the request?

I don't want to use any request mapping, just expose endpoints via `@RepositoryRestResource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RepositoryRestResource` doesn't expose any method of `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. If you want such behaviour you have to implement a controller and service to create Specification and execute it.